# why `1<<32 - 1` is 4294967295 in go?

Tags: c, go, bit-shift

I found a weird result in Go, could you help me?

```golang
fmt.Print( 1<<32 - 1)

it's 4294967295
```

But in C

```
 printf("%lld",0x1ll<<32 - 1);
it's 2147483648
```

Comment: https://blog.golang.org/constants

Comment: `%d` is `-1`, not 4294967295

Comment: ` printf("%d",(0x1ll<<32) - 1);` the same result as you said!

Comment: `1<<32 - 1` is undefined behavior in C for 32-bit ints, because `1<<31` is not representable.  So `printf("%u", 1<<32 - 1)` is UB for two reasons -- first you overflow an int, and second you use the wrong formatting string. The answer appears correct, but it's the result of two undefined behaviors which cancel each other out. (The cpu is doing 2's complement arithmetic mod 2^32, and then re-interpreting the negative value as a positive unsigned one when printing it out).

Comment: A little experimentation would have helped you find the answer yourself. For example, trying smaller values than 32 for the shift to see the pattern. And asking what _are_ the numbers that are output (ie: 2^32 - 1 and 2^31) and then figuring out why the two versions of the code gives those numbers. Also, experience in C teaches you that C operator precedence is weird in places, so whenever you have an expression that doesn't have brackets, you should bracket it if it's doing something strange.

Comment: Because the language spec says so and Go is not C.

Comment: I don't agree with the votes to close this question as a typo or unreproducible. It's obviously reproducible, and not the result of a typo -- it's about a confusing detail of the go grammar vs c grammar, which seems perfectly on-topic for stackoverflow, and a reasonable question.

Answer (score 17):

In go, `1<<32-1` parses as `(1 << 32) - 1` (which gofmt helpfully hints at with the spaces it inserts). In C, it parses as `1 << (32 - 1)`. This is because in C, shifts have lower precedence than + and -, and in go, it's the other way round.

You can see this in the output, in go it's *odd*, and is `4294967295` which is 2^32 - 1. In C it's `2147483648` which is 2^31.

Go operator precendence (from https://golang.org/ref/spec#Operators)

```
Precedence    Operator
    5             *  /  %  <<  >>  &  &^
    4             +  -  |  ^
    3             ==  !=  <  <=  >  >=
    2             &&
    1             ||
```

In C: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 4):

The key difference between C and Go here is operator precedence.

In C, `-` has higher precedence[1] than `<<`, so `1 << 32 - 1` is `1 << (32 - 1)` i.e. `1 << 31`.

In Go, it's the other way round[2], so `1 << 32 - 1` is `(1 << 32) - 1`.

This is made more confusing because the first Google result when you search for "go operator precedence" is not the spec I linked, but the tutorial at tutorialspoint.com (which I won't link), which gets this completely wrong - in fact, it appears to have copied the C operator precedence section verbatim from its C tutorial, including the precedence table, which contains lots of operators that do not even *exist* in Go.

[1] https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence
[2] https://golang.org/ref/spec#Operator_precedence

Comment: Technically, the ISO C spec doesn't use an operator-precedence parser at all. But the grammar it uses produces the same *effect* as if C had operator precedence, so this is right (plus: good warning on the bad Go tutorial!).